# Don't receive FCM notification

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with implementing FCM into my project. The problem is that i implementing FCM like in documentation but i don't receive test notification. I have similar project and the same implementation, but it works in another project and not in current:

My service:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
       super.onMessageReceived(p0)

        Log.d("RECEIVED", "MESSAGE RECEIVED")
        sendNotification(p0)
    }

    private fun sendNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage){

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val channelId = "fcm_channel"
        val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this,
            channelId
        )
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.notification?.title)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.notification?.body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

            val channel: NotificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "Channel human readable title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Складу ЗНО"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <service
            android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: have you manage your project in firebase?

Comment: @mingchen , yes, of course